# how to manage space in Jquery : 48 function calls (96 lines each) for HTML class variable

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, regex

I have shown below part of HTML code . Clearly there are two kind of options -

ICMP Error messages (8 options) and ICMP Informational Messages (around 30 options).

Total 48 options are there and for each selection, it will show its corrresponding paket structure.

First,have a look at HTML.

```
   <tr class="icmperr"><td>
     <select name="icmpmsgerrtyp"  id="icmpmsgerrtyp">
          <option value="res" onclick="icmptyp();">0-Reserved</option>
          <option value="desun" onclick="icmptyp();">1-Destination Unreachable</option>
          <option value="ptb" onclick="icmptyp();">2-Packet Too Big</option>
          <option value="timeex" onclick="icmptyp();">3-Time Exceeded</option>
          <option value="paraprob" onclick="icmptyp();">4-Parameter Problem</option>
        <option value="privex" onclick="icmptyp();">100-Private Experimentation</option>
       <option value="privex1" onclick="icmptyp();">101-Private Experimentation</option>
       <option value="resexp" onclick="icmptyp();">127-Reserved For expansion Of ICMPv6 Error Messages </option>
       </select> <br\>

  </td></tr>


   <tr class="icmpinfo"><td>
     <select name="icmpinfotyp"  id="icmpinfotyp">
     <option value="echoreq" onclick="icmptyp();">128-Echo Request</option>
     <option value="echorep" onclick="icmptyp();">129-Echo Reply</option>
     <option value="mlq" onclick="icmptyp();">130-Multicast Listener Query</option>
     <option value="mlr" onclick="icmptyp();">131-Multicast Listener Report</option>
     <option value="mld" onclick="icmptyp();">132-Multicast Listener Done</option>
     <option value="rs" onclick="icmptyp();">133-Router Solicitation(NDP)</option>
     <option value="ra" onclick="icmptyp();">134-Router Advertisement(NDP)</option>
     <option value="ns" onclick="icmptyp();">135-Neighbour Solicitation(NDP)</option>
     <option value="na" onclick="icmptyp();">136-Neighbour Advertisement(NDP)</option>
     <option value="redmsg" onclick="icmptyp();">137-Redirect Message(NDP)</option>
     <option value="rr" onclick="icmptyp();">138-Router Renumbering</option>
     <option value="niq" onclick="icmptyp();">139-ICMP Node Information Query</option>
     <option value="nir" onclick="icmptyp();">140-ICMP Node Information    
     Response</option>
     <option value="indsm" onclick="icmptyp();">141-Inverse Neighbor Discovery 
     Solicitation Message</option>
     <option value="indam" onclick="icmptyp();">142-Inverse Neighbor Discovery 
     Advertisement Message</option>
     <option value="mldr" onclick="icmptyp();">143-Multicast Listener Discovery (MLDv2) 
     Reports</option>
     <option value="hadreqm" onclick="icmptyp();">144-Home Agent Address Discovery 
     Request Message</option>
     <option value="hadresm" onclick="icmptyp();">145-Home Agent Address Discovery 
     Reply Message</option>
     <option value="mps" onclick="icmptyp();">146-Mobile Prefix Solicitation</option>
     <option value="mpa" onclick="icmptyp();">147-Mobile Prefix Advertisement</option>
     <option value="cps" onclick="icmptyp();">148-Certification Path Solicitation (SEND)
     </option>
     <option value="cpa" onclick="icmptyp();">149-Certification Path Advertisement 
     (SEND)</option>
     <option value="mra" onclick="icmptyp();">151-Multicast Router Advertisement 
     (MRD)</option>
     <option value="mrs" onclick="icmptyp();">152-Multicast Router Solicitation 
     (MRD)</option>
     <option value="mrt" onclick="icmptyp();">153-Multicast Router Termination 
     (MRD)</option>
     <option value="rcm" onclick="icmptyp();">155-RPL Control Message</option>
     <option value="pex" onclick="icmptyp();">200-Private Experimentation</option>
     <option value="pex1" onclick="icmptyp();">201-Private Experimentation</option>
     <option value="resexpim" onclick="icmptyp();">255-Reserved for expansion of ICMPv6 
     informational messages</option>


     </select> <br\>
     </td></tr>
```

now suppose I want to specify options for ICMP Inofrmational message-ECHO Request.

so it will be like -

```
  <option value="echoreq" onclick="icmptyp();echoreq();">128-Echo   
  Request</option>

  and then a jquery function echoreq() will go like this -


   function echoreq() {

      $(".echoreq").css("visibility", "visible");
      $(".echoreq").css("display", "table-row");  

      and 47*2 lines to make others invisible

   }
```

and there will be around 48 such functions. So it will go very lenghty.

so is there any suggestion how can I save space, may be by using showing some sort 
  of smartness in using class/function names or using any regex somewhere but not
  sure.

Please excuse If I am missing something trivial. Edit required in title also.
  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I used it in this way. Now what's wrong here ?

**Sample HTML -**

```
    <tr class="icmppac icmppacdesun">
       <td width="249">Unused</td>
       <td width="249"><input type="text" name="icmppacdesun" size="20"  
       id="icmppacdesun"/> [Default : 0] </td>
    </tr>
```

and function call like this -

```
  <option value="desun" onclick="icmptyp();icmppacstr('.icmppacdesun');">1-Destination 
  Unreachable</option>
```

and jquery like this -

```
    function icmppacstr(myobject) {

                     $(myobject).css("visibility", "visible");
                     $(myobject).css("display", "table-row");

                     $(".icmppac").css("visibility", "hidden");
                     $(".icmppac").css("display", "none");

    }
```

**EDIT2:**

```
  ....... 
  <select name="icmpmsgerrtyp"  id="icmpmsgerrtyp" onchange="myfun2(this.value)">
  ..... 
  <select name="icmpinfotyp"  id="icmpinfotyp" onchange="myfun2(this.value)">
  ....
```

and myfun2 was like this...

```
 function myfun2(object)
 {
  if(object=="desun")
  {

   // working fine 
   icmppacstr('.icmppacdesun');
  }
 //and so on for first select

  if(object=="echoreq")
  {
   alert('hi'); // its getting printed
   icmppacstr('.icmppacechoreq'); // but its not executing
  }
 //and so on for second select     


}
```

Its working out fine for options corresponding to first select but nothing is happening for when I select any one from second select options.

Comment: `Clearly there are two kind of options`. It isn't that clear actually. Could you reduce the amount of html provided to the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to create separate functions? 
You can simply create one function and pass the parameters to it.
Eg:

```
    function myfun(myobject) {

          $(myobject).css("visibility", "visible");
          $(myobject).css("display", "table-row");
       }
```

Rather than calling onclick of option after checking your edit i'll suggest use onchange of select.
So it will look like this.

```
<select name="icmpinfotyp"  id="icmpinfotyp" onchange="myfun2(this.value)">
```

and function will be like this

```
function myfun2(object)
{
  if(object=="desun")
  {
    icmptyp();
    icmppacstr('.icmppacdesun');
    // in my case myfun('.icmppacdesun');
  }
  //and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks fr d suggestion ... but its also not working out please check my edit again

Comment: your coding seems fine may be it's not going inside "if" try to debug there by adding alert and see whether it goes in "if" or not also above of "if" add alert so you will know that myfun2 gets called or not, i think it will get called only problem with "if" if it doesn't go inside "if" just remove space in options. or use jquery eg if($.trim(object)=="desun") i hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: have a look at the edit again please ... alert box is executing fine

Comment: are you getting any error, which error? can you share firebug console screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you try to do, as your problem is very specific for your case... As I understand, you have multiple elements on your page, each with a given class name and you want to avoid call hide on all of the elements.

What you could do is to give every element two classes. One that is specific for each element and one that is shared accross all elements.

Lets say, we have the three elements Item1, Item2 and Item3. Then you would do something like this:

```
<div class="item item-1"</div>
<div class="item item-2"</div>
<div class="item item-3"</div>
```

Now you would have to change your function a little bit. Introduce a parameter, that specifies the class of the item, that should be shown:

```
function echoreq(var displayItem) {
    $(".item").css("display", "none");
    $(displayItem).css("display", "table-row");  
}
```

Just make sure, that you update your calls

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple.

You can condense it down to four lines and get rid of all of those ugly inline HTML `onclick`s.

```
// select every option tag beneath id icmpinfotyp and id icmpmsgerrtyp
// bind the click function to all of those elements
$('#icmpinfotyp option, #icmpmsgerrtyp option').click(function() {
   // by using $(this), we only apply the css changes to whichever element is clicked on
   $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
   $(this).css("display", "table-row");
});
```

Now modify this for your needs as expected. No reason why you should have 48 separate functions. Let's use automation to our advantage!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onclick` on `<option>` - it won't work in all browsers. Instead, use `onchange` on the `<select>`.

Also, add a common class to all your packets/information items so they're easier to show and hide. Let's say the class is called `.option-item` so a single item might be:

```
<div class="option-item echoreq">...</div>
```

And the code could look like this:

```
// First, let's cache all the packets/option items for future reference:
var $optionItems = $('.option-item');

$('#icmpinfotyp').on('change', function(){
    // using .val() you get the contents of the value atttribute
    // of the selected option
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    // now hide all packets/option items:
    $optionItems.css({'visibility': 'hidden','display': 'none'}); // or use jQuery .hide()
    // and show the selected:
    $('.' + selectedValue).css({'visibility': 'visible','display': 'table-row'});

});
```